# Is it ok to send normal messages via Interface Builder's binding’s model key path?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nswindow, cocoa-bindings

Is it ok to send normal messages via Interface Builder's binding’s *model key path*?

I want to enable some menu items only if the main window of my application is visible. I simply tried the following to see what would happen:

In the bindings inspector of the menu item i bind *Availability-Enabled* to the `AppDelegate` and set the model key path to `self.window.isVisible`.

[image]

This seems to work well, but is it meant to be used like this? Legal in the AppStore?
A little exclamation mark appears next to my model key path..

Comment: I think that `isVisible` might be the getter name and the property is `visible`?

Comment: Yes, `self.window.visible` does also work. But is a property `visible` documented anywhere? Can i use this? Still apart from the special case, i am also interested in the general idea about what can be used in Model Key Path.

Comment: I just found `visible` in the cocoa bindings reference for NSWindow - but this does reference a binding for NSWindow, you can bind something to `visible`, not the other way round?: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSWindow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSWindow-SW1

Comment: It don't see why it's necessarily a read-only binding.  I'd imagine you could bind a control to a window's visible and the user toggling it would be changing the window's visible state.  Could be useful for accessory windows.  I haven't tried it though... you figure it out and answer your own question, maybe.  It also seems entirely reasonable to use to hide menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This binding is legal **if** the model property (`isVisible`) conforms to KVO (key-value observing), because bindings are implemented using KVO.

(UPDATED) [`NSWindow` has several documented binding keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSWindow.html), including the key `visible`.  Since the standard KVC search pattern would look for `isVisible` for the key `visible`, what you're doing will probably always work.  But you would be better off just binding to `visible`, since that's documented.

The important lesson is that you should only bind to keys that are documented for Cocoa bindings, or keys that are documented to be KVO-compliant.

The exclamation mark is Xcode's way of warning you that it doesn't know if the binding is legal.  You can hover your mouse pointer over it for a tooltip:

[image: “Xcode cannot resolve the entered keypath”]